# How could i include one tempate in another with html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

I have code like this:

```
<script id="innerTemplate" type="text/template">
  Hello world
</script>
```

and code like this:

```
<script id="outerTemplate" type="text/template">
  My name is John!
  <p>
     /*Here i want to include the code of the innerTemplate*/
  </p>
</script>
```

Does sombody know how to do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean something like this with the `my-customer` directive? http://plnkr.co/edit/mWHRVBMfCA6kZGtiZNkx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can try with that:

```
<script id="innerTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
  Hello world
</script>


<script id="outerTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
  My name is John!
  <p ng-include="'innerTemplate'"></p>
</script>

<div ng-include="'outerTemplate'"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vMjhMZorNqhpxYAO7e9z

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS you only need an HTML file like this:

`include.html`:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

And then in another HTML file like `index.html`:

```
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <div ng-include="include.html"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/knOHrf?p=preview

i think what you need is [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) :

your innerTemplate.(assuming u saved it in "view/innerTemplate.html")

```
<div>
  Hello world
</div>
```

and code like this:

```
<script id="outerTemplate" type="text/template">
  My name is John!
  <p>
     <div ng-include="view/innerTemplate.html"></div>
  </p>
</script>
```

or assuming your adding the innerTemplate in the same file 
try this :

```
<script id="innerTemplate" type="text/template">
      Hello world
 </script>

 <script id="outerTemplate" type="text/template">
      My name is John!
      <p>
         <div ng-include="innerTemplate"></div>
      </p>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link exactly as you want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/74k8kptc/10/

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="innerTemplate.html">
       Hello world
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="outerTemplate.html">
        My name is John!

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <ng-include src="'innerTemplate.html'"></ng-include>
    <ng-include src="'outerTemplate.html'"></ng-include>

</body>
```